# Can I compare prices to a metal? "Zinc prices, like nickel, declined…"

Tags: word-usage

I originally used 'nickel prices'. A freelancer who is a native speaker changed it to 'nickel'. Now he is comparing prices to a metal. Is this acceptable?

> **Zinc prices, like nickel**, declined only from July to October, by no
> more than 1%.

[image]

Comment: The freelancer is an opinionated pedant. The meaning is obvious, and *this* native speaker would rather see your straightforward phrasing than the pointlessly / distractingly verbose *Zinc prices, like **those of** nickel, declined...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - needless repetition can be vexing, and remind one of the school essays of a nine year old. Copper prices, like iron prices, steel prices, nickel prices, zinc prices, gold prices, and silver prices, declined from July to October.

Comment: No.   The repetition is absolutely necessary here.  You'd lose points in high school English class for this.    Google "parallel construction".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native speakers often omit words when the meaning is clear, especially if it avoids repetition (e.g. of 'prices'). This practice is called ellipsis (not to be confused with the three-dot punctation mark of the same name).

> Ellipsis happens when we leave out (in other words, when we don’t use)
> items which we would normally expect to use in a sentence if we
> followed the grammatical rules.

[Ellipsis (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/ellipsis)

Consider:

**Zinc prices, like *[those of]* nickel, declined only from July to October, by no more than 1%.** Here, 'those of' makes the sentence more 'formal', but can be omitted without damaging the meaning for a native speaker or reader.

**Zinc prices, like nickel *[prices]*, declined only from July to October, by no more than 1%.**
Here, the second, repeated, instance of 'prices', although strictly necessary for formal grammatical correctness, has been omitted.

Native speakers *understand* that prices are being discussed, either because that word is mentioned once in a sentence, or if it is obviously the topic under discussion (e.g. it is in the title).

Comment: The use in OP is not ellipsis.  It's simply incorrect.

Comment: @BadZen Says what resource? At least three native speakers here think it's acceptable.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I see where you're going with this answer, but it doesn't directly address the question. Can you directly tie in what you're saying about ellipsis to the OP's question instead of leaving it implied?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's acceptable, but it's unjustifiably picky and unnecessarily clumsy.

The captions of the graph clearly identify the issue as metal prices. In this context, it would also be entirely natural to say, "Zinc, like nickel, declined ...". In either case, "prices" are simply assumed, and the omission of the word will have no effect on the comprehensibility of the statement.

Answer (score -4):

You are correct.  Change it back.

You should always prefer parallel construction in lists of noun phrases in English.   You are correct about the right way to say this, and you are also correct about the *way in which it sounds wrong* to a fluent speaker ("comparing prices to a metal").

It would also be OK to say "**nickel, like zinc, declined...**".  Even though it is not the physical metal that is declining, the construction ios now parallel, the meaning is clear and the omission of the word "prices" *is* an example of "ellipsis".

You can read more about parallel construction here:

https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/effective-writing/parallel-construction/

Comment: Coconut prices, like cocoa, rice and maize, have declined. Perfectly OK.

Comment: This is basic grammar and literally every textbook disagrees with you, Michael.   Please provide a source or other evidence that makes you think this is correct usage.

(read eg. https://www.iup.edu/writingcenter/writing-resources/grammar/parallel-structure.html)