# Are there words missing from "Agriculture accounts for 80% of water consumption..."?

Tags: sentence-construction

In the first clause, I think **agriculture** is short for **agriculture water consumption**. People understand that water consumption is being discussed so can be omitted. What about the second clause? I think it means economic activity accounts for only 2% of water consumption. How can it be shortened to **only 2% of economic activity**? Please explain.

> Agriculture accounts for 80% of water consumption in California, for
> example, but only 2% of economic activity. [The Economist](https://www.economist.com/united-states/2014/02/22/the-drying-of-the-west?ah=308cac674cccf554ce65cf926868bbc2&zid=311)

I understand that account for can mean "make up" or "form". Women form 25 percent of our employees. "Women" and "employees" are both humans. Humans form humans. But agriculture and water consumption are two different things. How can agriculture form water consumption? It should be agricultural water consumption form water consumption. That's why I interpret it as "agriculture" being short for "agricultural water consumption".

Comment: 'Agriculture' is a noun that stands alone and means 'farming'. It is one kind of economic activity. That activity uses 80% of the water consumed in California. That same activity is 2% of all economic activity in California.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, thanks for the comment. About the first clause, yes, that activity uses water but that activity does account for water. Can I understand it as Ellipsis you mentioned in this question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/339456/can-i-compare-prices-to-a-metal-zinc-prices-like-nickel-declined

Comment: No: "agriculture" is not short for anything; it simply means the practice of farming. The reference to water consumption is expressed in the complement "water consumption in California. The two expressions "80% of water consumption in California" and "only 2% of economic activity" form a coordination of NPs serving as complement of "for".

Comment: @BillJ, thanks. About your comment "agriculture" is not short for anything", this new quote uses "agriculture water use" instead of 'agriculture". How can you explain?
**Agricultural water use accounts for 96% of the total water use in this region**

Comment: Just another way of saying the same thing.

Comment: My point is that if you compare the two quotes, you can see "agriculture" is short for "agricultural water use".

Comment: The only words omitted are 'it accounts for': "Agriculture accounts for 80% of water consumption in California, but [it accounts for] only 2% of economic activity.

Comment: As a rule, I never question the English in The Economist. It could not be clearer. It is not short of anything. It's just water consumption in agriculture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Agriculture accounts for 80% of water consumption in California, for example, but only 2% of economic activity.

This sentence is talking about the portion of agricultural water consumption compared to all other types of water consumption in California. Agriculture uses the most water (80%) but contributes very little to the overall economic activity in California (2%).

The relevant [definition of 'account for' from Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/account%20for%20(something)) is:

> to be the cause of (something)
> *These new features account for the computer's higher price.*

Another example:

> Foreign nationals account for half of the increase in employment in the last year.
> *The Guardian (2016)* (Retrieved from [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sentences/english/account-for)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand that **account for** can mean **make up** or **form**. Women form 25 percent of our employees. "Women" and "employees" are both humans. Humans form humans. But agriculture and water consumption are two different things. How can agriculture form water consumption? It should be agricultural water consumption form water consumption. That's why I interpret it as "agriculture" being short for "agricultural water consumption". But you guys all say nothing is omitted. I hope you understand what I am confused about.

Comment: @newbieforever Ah, I see the problem now... maybe "to be the cause of" is the better choice of definition. I grabbed the other one because it seemed like it was more similar to your example, but I missed the nuance there.

Comment: Finally understood. Thank you very much.

Comment: There are no words omitted. This is a simple coordination construction where the two expressions "80% of water consumption in California" and "only 2% of economic activity" form a coordination of NPs serving as complement to the preposition "for" in "Agriculture accounts for ..."

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I probably shouldn't be trying to answer questions on my phone while multitasking at work. Thanks for pointing this out.